# How to fix "OperationalError: near 'n': syntax error" syntax error in sqlite3 using python 3.5

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, syntax-error

I get operational error in `self.cur.execute(...)` specified in header when calling function:

```
    def get_synset(self, pos, sense, literal):

        with self.conn:
            self.cur.execute("SELECT id FROM wordnet_entry WHERE pos = '{}' AND sense = '{}' AND literal = '{}' LIMIT 1".format(pos, sense, literal))
            synset_id = self.cur.fetchone()[0]

            return Synset(self, synset_id)
```

I'm using jupyter notebook. The function itself is in file.py. It is accessed by import

```
from dir import file.py
```

Error code:

```
    OperationalError   Traceback (most recent call last)
     47         with self.conn:
---> 48             self.cur.execute("SELECT id FROM wordnet_entry WHERE pos = '{}' AND sense = '{}' AND literal = '{}' LIMIT 1".format(pos, sense, literal))*
     49             synset_id = self.cur.fetchone()[0]
     50 

OperationalError: near "n": syntax error
```

The error message seems ambiguous to me.

*EDIT

I posted wrong error message. It has one extra AND condition:

```
 ---> 48  self.cur.execute("SELECT id FROM wordnet_entry WHERE pos = '{}' AND sense = '{}' AND literal = '{}' LIMIT 1".format(pos, sense, literal))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since you're not using bound variables and are instead simply formatting a string query (this is a bad idea by the way as it can easily allow SQL injection attacks), your first step should probably be to find out what's actually *in* those three variable.

A simple:

```
print("SELECT id FROM wordnet_entry WHERE pos = '{}' AND sense = '{}' AND literal = '{}' LIMIT 1".format(pos, sense, literal))
```

before running the query should hopefully tell you everything you need to know about the query, including whether it's malformed or not.

Comment: Appreciated. Is this safe against injection?    
  

`self.cur.execute("SELECT id FROM wordnet_entry WHERE pos = ? AND sense = ? AND literal = ? LIMIT 1", (pos, sense, literal))`

Comment: @flowian: yes, I believe that is the correct syntax for SQLite.